# How to send my form using ajax if I have 3 different forms on one page?

Tags: django

I have main page with 3 pop up box with forms. How to send my form using ajax if I have 3 forms on one page?

For one form per page I have something like this:

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    websites = Website.objects.all()
    form = WebsiteModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            status = "ok"
            return HttpResponse(status)
        else:
            return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form, 'websites': websites}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = WebsiteModelForm()
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form, 'websites': websites}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

jquery:

```
$('#demo').submit(function(event) {
  var $form = $(this);
  var serializedData = $form.serialize();
  $.post('/', serializedData, function(response) {
    alert("Done");
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have need 3 url for post form, then variant:

1. Add action path to every form. And add one common class to every form.(for ex- class="form_post")

2.

```
$('.form_post').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $.post($form.attr('action'), serializedData, function(response) {
        alert("Done");
        ....
```